# How to validate if the table is empty with capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have tried all these commands but none works. I even used some tips from StackOverflow but I wasn't happy yet..
I have tried all these commands but none works. I even used some tips from StackOverflow but I wasn't happy yet..
I have tried all these commands but none works. I even used some tips from StackOverflow but I wasn't happy yet..

```rb
expect(find('.tvGrid').has_no_content?).to be true
expect(find('.tvGrid')).to have_no_content
expect(find('.tvGrid > tbody', visible: false)).not_to have_css('td')
expect(find('.tvGrid > tbody')).to have_no_content
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="tvGrid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Id</th>
      <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Code</th>
      <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Description</th>
      <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Operational Center</th>
      <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: <table width="100%" class="tvGrid">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Id</th>
                <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Código</th>
                </tr>
            <tr class="tvRowEmpty">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to format in the body of the issue

Comment: @mechnicov 
Okay, I got it!! I updated my doubt putting the html.  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you can check that there is no text inside `td` nodes. There are many ways to do it

As example

```
expect(all('.tvGrid td').any? { |td| td.text.present? }).to be false
```

or

```
expect(all('.tvGrid td').select { |td| td.text.present? }).to be_empty
```

or

```
expect(all('.tvGrid td').all? { |td| td.text.blank? }).to be true
```

`.blank?` and `.present?` are ActiveSupport methods. In vanilla Ruby you can use `.strip.empty?` instead of these methods

Comment: @mechinicov All methods return errors:   undefined method `all?' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All:0x0000027c296e9a18>                                                       undefined method `select?' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All:0x0000027c296e9a18> undefined method `any?' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All:0x0000027c296e9a18>

Comment: @Elis try `page.all('.tvGrid td')` instead of just `all('.tvGrid td')`

Comment: These will lead to flaky tests if you have a dynamic page because they disable Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior

Comment: I have a doubt, do you prefer that I open another call or can we solve it here? In this list I want to return blank records. If I have only one record, it will list all blank lines.  page.all('.tvGrid tr > td:nth-child(5)').each do |td|
   puts td.text

Comment: It's better to open new question

Answer (score 1):

The key here is tell Capybara to expect no `td` elements with contents.  You can use the fact the `text` option can be a Regexp here to check for that

```
expect(page).not_to have_css('.tvGrid td', text: /.+/)
```

This will make Capybara ensure there are no elements matching the `.tvGrid td` selector with 1 or more characters of text content, and will retry that for up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds to account for dynamic pages. You can adjust the Regexp as necessary to allow any acceptable contents.